# How to get image path by node ID in Drupal 6?

Tags: wordpress, drupal

Currently, I have a Drupal website and I was used imagecache to upload and create thumbnail for each post.
And I want convert all data from Drupal to wordpress. I was converted all post, comments, users...from Drupal to Wordpress successfly. It's exist one issue with images thumbnails.
So, now I have a question, 
**It's:  How to get image path by Node ID without code Drupal?**
I want to use phpMyAdmin or run simple PHP code to get results.
Have someone help me?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that all of your images are uploaded to a specific field inside the Drupal articles. I would suggest to have a look at the relevant field in the database, for example content_field_FIELDNAME.

There, you can find the nid (node ID) and field_FIELDNAME_fid (file ID) field. You can find the file you want from its ID in the files table, field fid. The file path is in the filepath field in that table. Therefore, you can link the following:

field_FIELDNAME_fid table: node ID (article ID), field_FIELDNAME_fid (file ID) --> foreign key for the primary key fid in the files table, from where you can find the file from the filepath field

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I have a table content_field_image. But the issue is when I check nid field in table Node with nid field in table content_field_image -> it has a disparity! the nid fields in node table not exist in content_field_image table!

Comment: Sounds like leftover junk... can you view these nodes by navigating to site.com/node/XXX? It's normal NOT to have all nodes inside the content_field_FIELDNAME table - not all pages contain pictures. The inverse sounds like you're missing data and the images are orphaned - unless they're somehow used elsewhere, by some other module?

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try find again. Because I don't created this site from start so I'm not sure struct of it right.